# how do i make this javascript logic + syntax (very simple)

Tags: javascript

Why I am getting true all the time?

```
var _template_id = "";
if (_template_id != '0' || _template_id!="")  {
        alert("true")
}else{
    alert("false")
}
```

or even if i set _template_id="0", it still turns out as true...

Comment: Because `''` is not `0` and `0` is not `''`  :-P For what values of `_template_id` do you want it to say `true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `&&` not `||`.

It must always be true because `"0" != ""`, so one or the other is always true.

Answer (score 4):

Because you're asking if _template_id isn't equal to "0" OR isn't equal to "". One of those will always be true.

Proof: Given your statement of `(_template_id != '0' || _template_id!="")`, let's suppose that the first part is false. Therefore `_template_id == '0'` is true, and hence `_template_id != ""` is true, so overall the statement evaluates to true.

If, on the other hand, the first part is true, then clearly the whole thing evaluates to true again.

Therefore, the statement is always true.

Answer (score 2):

`a != b || a != c` is always true when `b` and `c` are different.

What you want here is probably to use

```
if (!(_template_id == '0' || _template_id ==""))  {
    alert("true")
```

Then if you set  `_template_id="0"` you would get `false` as desired.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want

```
!(_template_id == '0' || _template_id == "")
```

If `_template_id` is neither `0` nor `''`.

This is equivalent (thanks to [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)) to:

```
_template_id != '0' && _template_id != ""
```

Comment: Nice reference. Distributive propositional logic FTW. An upvote for you, sir. :)

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to change the value of _template_id ? I will always be true if you assign "" and then ask if its '0' or "" then true.

Answer (score 0):

You are logically going wrong.
Either use == and ¦¦
Or
Use != and &&

It will result the same in both cases and your condition will be true as well.